# Youtube add-ons for Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, youtube

Recently I have installed two youtube video downloader add-ons(easy youtube video downloader express 8.01, easiest youtube video downloader 7.2) in my Firefox browser (v-37.0). But they don't work at all. I  refreshed the Firefox just 4 days ago. Even easy Youtube video downloader express 8.01 worked fine somedays ago. Where's the problem , please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This add-on work for me:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-youtube/

https://github.com/gantt/downloadyoutube

[image]

It is very easy to use.
And the files to download are original files from Youtube.

Comment: Thanks much Alexander. Your add-on will be very helpul for me , I believe. But what's wrong with the easy youtube video downloader express 8.01 add-on which worked fine before ? Could you please have any explanation ? Thanks again